# PHP OOP function won't grab data unless another function is called

Tags: php, oop

I'm having this weird problem right now, I'm just working on a small admin backend thing that will allow users to upload a file and download it again, simple stuff.

I'm using PHP OOP with Classes and functions and things. Still pretty new at it. Currently on one page I have a "getRecentLinks" function that will call information from a couple tables and put it all out on the page in a table, it works just fine. One of the options on this page is to download the file that was uploaded to that individual row. So I just want it to be a link you click on to say, file-download.php?id=3.

Now on file-download.php I'm currently just testing to get the information on the page before I add the headers and things in there. So I just have a simple

```
$l = new Links();
$file = $l->getFileInfo($_GET['id']);
print_r($file);
```

this SHOULD just return information from the database, id, name of file, size, data, and mimetype.

Now this doesn't work. I have no idea why but it doesn't.

Now on my page where I have the getRecentLinks() function it works just fine. I even brought in the getRecentLinks() into my file-download.php page so it's setup like this.

```
$l = new Links();
$l->getRecentLinks();
$file = $l->getFileInfo($_GET['id']);
print_r($file);
```

This works just fine and dandy, The second I remove getRecentLinks() it stops calling information from getFileInfo() and I cannot figure it out. I mean it's not a huge deal i could just keep #l->getRecentLinks() there but I can see this getting annoying if I have to add it to every page I want to do something, I'm just at the start of this project.

Here's the code in the Links class

```
public function getFileInfo($id)
{
    $result = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM file WHERE id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");

    $resultSet = $this->fetch($result);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

and

```
public function getRecentLinks()
{
    $result = $this->runQuery("SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY date DESC");

    while($j = $this->fetch($result))
    {
        $resultSet[] = $j;
    }

    return $resultSet;
}
```

And heres my connections and fetch functions a friend helped me develop

```
public function runQuery($sql) {
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
    if(!$this->connection) {
        die("MySQL is down.");
    } else {
        mysql_select_db($this->dbname);
    }
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$this->connection) or die(mysql_error());

    return $result;
}

public function fetch($result)
{
    $resultSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: I have a couple question for you, because the problem isn't immediately apparent:


1. Do you have error reporting build into your query function? What error is occuring when you just run the "getFileInfo()" function?


2. What are you using to query MySql? It may be something as simple as having to flush all your result sets, if your using mysqli and multi query.

Comment: When you say `file-download.php` doesn't work, does it not print at all? It may not even be reaching the `print_r()`. Are there any errors? Call `error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on the top of the page and see if errors pop up.

Comment: where is connection to database?

Comment: @Fanis yeah it says I dont have access to use mysql_real_escape_string so maybe thats the problem? But I still don't understand why it would work otherwise when i call getRecentLinks()

Comment: oh yeah that is the problem... I can't use mysql_real_escape_string cause I get access denied for a user i'm not even using to connect to the database...

Comment: I hate when it's something simple like error_reporting to help figure out a problem thanks! Going to leave that on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string requires a connection. Since `getRecentLinks` opens a connection it works. But you call mysql_real_escape_string before `runQuery` (in execution order) in `getFileInfo`. In this case, I assume the id is an integer, so you're better off and a lot cheaper to call `intval($_GET['id'])`.